# invalid initializer member declarator using linq and entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am new to Linq with usage of Entity Framework entities. I have all the entity classes for each table created in the model. I need to retrieve data from multiple tables. Here I am trying to get Information from Person, Employee, Details tables. I have multiple joins in my query. I do not want to rewrite all the properties in a new class Details. Instead I used,

```
namespace DAL
{
    public class Details
    {
        public List<Person> provider { get; set; }
        public List<Employee> location { get; set; }
        public List<Details> member { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to use these properties in my custom method in my DAL class. But I am not able to get the Properties defined in these tables.

```
public List<Details> GetDetails(string dKey)
{
        try
        {

            using (var myDB = new Test_2013SQLEntities())
            {
                return (from H in myDB.Person
                        join L in myDB.Details on H.PID equals L.DID
                        join P in myDB.Employee on H.PersonID equals P.EmployeeID
                        where L.DID == dKey
                        select new Details()
                        {                                                           
                           ????? = L.DID,
                           ????? = H.Name,
                           ????? = P.PName
```

I need the DID property defined from Details table here. When I try putting the DID there, I am getting an error "**invalid initializer member declarator**" How can I access the properties in the entity Detail, Person, Employee here in the GetDetails method.

Please help!

Comment: `DID` is a single property and if you'll initialize it like : `new Details { provider = L.DID, location  = H.Name, member = P.PName }`, it will fail because `provider` is a list and you are trying to assign a single item. Can you post any sample data or the type of Person, Employee & db.Details too.

Comment: depending on your models definition you may don't need to join tables, instead you can use Include to load the navigation property, so update your question and include the definition of your models (Person, Employee and Details).

Comment: this other question should help you solve yours.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568587/linq-to-sql-select-into-a-new-class