# How to join tables using LINQ and navigation properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-relationship, navigation-properties

[Previous question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769737/how-to-join-tables-using-linq-to-entities-query)

Consider to my previous question (I put a link to it) I need to get some different information.

Here is a DB structure I only added navigation property

```
public virtual ICollection<Accident> Accidents { get; set; }
```

to Transport class

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Transport
{
    [Key]
    public int TransportID { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Accident> Accidents { get; set; }
}

public class Accident
{
    [Key]
    public int AccsidentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime AccidentDate { get; set; }
    public int TransportID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TransportID")]
    public virtual Transport Transport { get; set; }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonID")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
public class AccsidentObject
{
    [Key]
    public int AccidentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime AccidentDate { get; set; }
    public int TransportID { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
 }
```

If I want to get all accidents I use

```
var accidents = DBContext.Accidents.Select( a => new AccidentObject 
{ 
    AccidentID = a.AccidentId,
    AccidentDate 
    TransportID 
    Model 
    Brand = a.Transport.Brand,
    PersonID = a.Person.PersonID,
    FirstName 
    LastName 
});
```

What would be a code if I would like to select TransportObject with added specific Accident data

```
public class TransportObject
{
    [Key]
    public int TransportID { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public int AccidentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime AccidentDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
var transports = DBContext.Transports
        .SelectMany(
            x => x.Accidents, 
            (t, a) => new TransportObject 
            {
                TransportID = t.TransportID,
                Model = t.Model,
                Brand = t.Brand,
                AccidentID = a.AccidentId,
                AccidentDate = a.AccidentDate
            }
        );
```

More about select many in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549040(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: That is what I needed!! Actually I was lost in such a lot examples, so I modeled my structure and You @Niyoko Yuliawan help me so much! Than You